# Power automorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, examples-counterexamples, automorphism-group

I am currently studying group automorphism and I have come across the definition of **power automorphism**. It's first time I've heard it and I'd like to know who they really are. That is, to know examples, to know how I could apply them later or in which things that are already familiar to me are used. Thanks in advance

Comment: Isn't $f:G\to G$ a power automorphism if for any $g\in G$ there is $n$ such that $f(g)=g^n$? Hence the name. When $G$ is finite abelian and $n$ constant, relatively prime to $|G|$ then every such formula gives a power automorphism.